# Sum Emails Sizes From MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have been asked to perform a very basic query task in MongoDB however I am unable to understand how to properly query the collection w/ aggregate functions in proper syntax.

I need to query the email collection for all email attachment sizes & sum them for today. Customer is aksing me to group all the email attachements for just their account for a single day (today). How would I find this?

Below is the output of db.email.findOne():

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55893983e4b0ea8af5a61550"),
        "customer_id" : "12345",
        "Subject" : "test message",
        "Date" : ISODate("2016-08-04T10:48:13Z"),
        "headers" : [
        "Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 12:48:13 +0200 (CEST)",
        "From: user@domain.tld",
        "Message-ID: <240354118.javamail.email.server.tld>",
        "Subject: Cats",
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit",
        "To: undisclosed-recipients:;",
        "X-ClamAV: clean"
        ],
        "text" : "feed the cats please",
        "attachments" : [ ],
        "langprob" : 0.8301894511454121,
        "original_message_file_id" : "239863489r7637208",
        "account_id" : "xxx",
        "received_time" : ISODate("2015-06-23T10:48:35.097Z"),
        "direction" : "inbound",
        "state" : "CLOSED",
        "encryption_key_id" : null,
        "size" : 1651,
        "routing_type" : "PUSH",
        "priority" : 1,
        "closed_time" : ISODate("2015-07-10T21:02:53.409Z")
}
```

Can anyone please assist me in properly creating a query in JSON syntax to extract the data I need from MongoDB based on my predicates?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: When you say *today*, do you mean the *received_time*?

Comment: I'd suggest you do some reading, try a few things and report back with a starting point or questions. See http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/ for some examples.